# How To Load the latest data added in jquery

Tags: php

This is my PHP script and I want to load the latest data inputted first before the old data. Please help...

```
 /*call the contents from the founofficer*/
 if ($content=="foun"){
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT title,content FROM founofficer");
    $limit=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($limit==0){
        $disp.="No current foundation officers!";
    }
    else {
        for($j=1;$j<=$limit;$j++){
            $row=mysql_fetch_object($query);
            $disp.="<div id='hTitle'>".$row->title."</div>";
            $disp.="<div id='hContent'>".$row->content."</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: `mysql_query` iis deprecated, you should use `PDO` and search for  `->lastInsertId(); `

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is no way using jquery! But you can use setInterval function and send ajax request to your DB and get content if there is some change you can show new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with change in query

```
 $query=mysql_query("SELECT title,content FROM founofficer order by id asc"); //change as per your table column like id or srno etc and asc or desc as per your need...
```

Also mysqli or PDO is recommended...instead of mysql

Comment: why select everything? just use `LIMIT 1`

Comment: @NicolòCozzani because in question mentioned as  : I want to load the latest data inputted first before the old data...Not last record Only....

Comment: You are right, i tought with data op means data of last row +1

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried by ascending, it didn't work, so I tried by descending, it worked. Guess the data was saved the other way.:)))